# Boost log doesn't write to file, how to?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log, boost-logging

here is my code:

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/move/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT(my_logger, src::logger_mt)

void Foo::Some()
{
  std::cout << "TEST";

  src::logger_mt& lg = my_logger::get();

  logging::add_file_log("F:\\sample.log");
  //logging::core::get()->set_filter
  //  (
  //  logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
  //  );
  logging::add_common_attributes();

  BOOST_LOG(lg) << "Greetings from the global logger!";
```

it's taken from boost tutorial but it doesn't write to file and doesn't show any error messages

tutorial is here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_file.cpp

what am I doing wrong?

it works without line: `logging::add_file_log("F:\\sample.log");` but I was trying different file locations and it doesn't write anywhere

Comment: Is this all your code? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @robert yes if you will rename Foo::Some to main and add closing bracket... there is nothing additional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your logger does not have a severity attribute. It does not produce severity values in log records, and because of that the filter you set always rejects records.

In the example from the docs you linked you can see that `severity_logger` and `BOOST_LOG_SEV` are used for logging (see the docs [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sources.html#log.detailed.sources.severity_level_logger)). The `severity_logger` logger has the severity attribute of the type specified in the template argument, and the `BOOST_LOG_SEV` macro provides the severity value for every log record. Note that the type of the attribute value (the severity level) has to match the filter and formatter, if there are any installed. The `logging::trivial::severity` keyword in the filter you set implies that the severity level is expected to have type `boost::log::trivial::severity_level`.

Comment: thanks, it was the case here, odd that it only was causing file

Answer (score 3):

The file path `"F:\sample.log"` may be equivalent to `"F:sample.log"` when the escape sequence is taken care of. (this is implementation-defined, according to [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 2.14.3 Character literals)
`:` is not usable in names of files in Windows.
Did you mean `"F:\\sample.log"`?

Comment: thanks sure, but it was my typo, I've tasted with `\\\` and workflow is the same, I've tested just "sample.log" before and and did nothing either